# AngularJS accessing variable from controller throws Reference Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access a variable from the controller but it keeps giving me the below error. Not sure why it says vm is not defined.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: vm is not defined
>       at localhost/:1

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test" ng-controller="mainController as vm">

<head>
        <style id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var Meta = vm.Meta;
        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <section ui-view></section>
</body>
</html>
```

mainController.js

```
(function() {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("test")
    .controller("mainController", mainController);

mainController.$inject = [
    "$rootScope",
    "$window",
    "$scope",
    "$log",
    "UserService"
];

function mainController($rootScope, $window, $scope, $log, UserService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.Meta = function() {
        var Meta = {};
        UserService.getUserData().then(
            function(response) {
                if (response.data) {
                    Meta = response.data;
                    Meta.firstName = response.data.name || "";
                }
            }
        );
        return Meta;
    };
}
```

Comment: why do you have the script tag inside the head? also, why do you have a var assignment in that ref to something that you don't need?

Comment: This code: `<script type="text/javascript">var Meta = vm.Meta;</script>`

What are you trying to do here? This is an Angular anti-pattern.`vm` is not defined, because its outside of the scope. Angular has no idea what it is.

Comment: @couzzi I want to expose the Meta object as a javascript object so that a third party script can use that object.

Answer (score 0):

Attach `meta` to `$scope` instead of `this`:

```
$scope.Meta = function() { 
    ... 
}
```

Then, expose your scope in your inline `<script>` block:

```
var scope = angular.element( document.querySelector('[ng-app="test"]') ).scope();
var Meta = scope.Meta;
```

Also, no sure you gain anything in this scenario by using the `controller as` syntax, so change this to `ng-controller="mainController"`

Comment: Now it throws `(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at (index):1`

Comment: Then I believe the other poster here is correct. Is the HTML you posted your full HTML? If so, it lacks the required javascript includes. You're not including Angular.js, or your controller files. Please post all the code you have. A link to a plunkr.co or jsfiddle.net mirror would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you load mainController.js? I don't see it included in the `<head/>`

Furthermore, your example doesn't show the closing of the anonymous function and it's immediate invocation `(function (angular) {...})(angular);`

Comment: Fair point, but this is not an answer. Ask questions of OP in the comments thread of the question above.

Comment: I would if I could :). Sorry.